# Browser actions outside the viewport

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

If an iframe loads a page containing a javascript ticker, but the ticker is outside the viewport, will a browser still waste CPU on running the ticker?

Comment: Yes. similar to background processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the ticker implementation.  Most likely it will.

Answer (score 0):

yes - save for the nanosecond it would have used to color in the pixels :-)